# Why is django manage.py syncdb failing to create new columns on my development server?

Tags: django, django-models, django-manage.py

I am trying to create a development server from a production server from which I can test out new ideas.

I created a duplicate of my production server's database by dumping it using Postgres' `db_dump` and then imported the dump into a new database.

I then copied my production django directory and altered all `.py` files to refer to `server_debug.` rather than `server` in my `import` statements.

Using the admin interface to alter some data works in that only the development server has its data altered.

However, when I then try adding a new field in my `models.py` in my development server, `manage.py syncdb` fails to create it.

Is there something I am neglecting that could cause `manage.py` to refer to my production server rather than my development server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`syncdb` doesn't touch tables that already exist. You need to either reset the app (easiest if you don't care about the data), modify the table manually (more of a quick hack) or use a migration app and version your models — [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), for example.

Comment: Perhaps I am using the wrong terms in my question, but if I create a new piece of data in my models.py file, say:
`middle_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)`
Then don't I need to run `manage.py` to add this column the database? 
This is in a preexisting class.

Comment: Looking through the documentation I see you are right. I'm now completely baffled by this. I thought one of Django's features was that it doesn't require one to actually go through and supply SQL directly to your database. I could understand if one alters a column Django won't know what to do with existing data. But if I am adding a new column, why can't Django just issue the commands for me?